# Logitech unifying receiver not working after upgrade to 14.04

Tags: 14.04, 12.04, upgrade, logitech, logitech-unifying

I paired my K520 keyboard and M705 mouse with a Unifying receiver on Windows. When I plugged the receiver into my Ubuntu 12.04 machine it worked fine. However, after I upgraded to 14.04, my keyboard and mouse are no longer working.

`lsusb | grep Logitech` output:

```
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
```

`dmesg | grep Logitech` output:

```
[54.126593] usb 3-4: Manufacturer: Logitech
```

I installed Solaar, but it gives this error message:

*No Logitech receiver found*

How do I make it so that they are detected?

Comment: Are you plugging the Logitech dongle directly into a USB port on the computer, or into a USB hub? Try plugging it directly into a port on the computer. Have you upgraded the firmware in the dongle? If not, go to the Logitech site and download the updater.

Comment: @heynnema I am using notebook, and I am plugging it directly. I have just checked and it seems that my firmware is up to date. Any other idea?

Comment: Do you have another Logitech receiver dongle that you can try? Do you have another computer running Ubuntu to try it on? You could also try booting to a Ubuntu 16.10 Live DVD and see if it works there.